# Using ViewModelProvider get with key results in IllegalArgumentException:SavedStateProvider with the given key is already registered

Tags: android, viewmodel, android-lifecycle, android-viewmodel, dagger-hilt

I would like to get separate instances of a ViewModel class from a fragment. I tried

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class MyFragment: Fragment() {

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        ...
        val vm1 = ViewModelProvider(this).get("100", MyViewModel::class.java)
        val vm2 = ViewModelProvider(this).get("200", MyViewModel::class.java)
        ...
        //// viewmodel objects are passed downstream to other modules where they
        //// will be used
    }
}
```

But I see the crash `IllegalArgumentException:SavedStateProvider with the given key is already registered`. Using lifecycle version `2.4.1`.

```
AndroidRuntime: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: SavedStateProvider with the given key is already registered
AndroidRuntime:        at androidx.savedstate.SavedStateRegistry.registerSavedStateProvider(SavedStateRegistry.java:111)
AndroidRuntime:        at androidx.lifecycle.SavedStateHandleController.attachToLifecycle(SavedStateHandleController.java:50)
AndroidRuntime:        at androidx.lifecycle.SavedStateHandleController.create(SavedStateHandleController.java:70)
AndroidRuntime:        at androidx.lifecycle.AbstractSavedStateViewModelFactory.create(AbstractSavedStateViewModelFactory.java:67)
AndroidRuntime:        at androidx.lifecycle.AbstractSavedStateViewModelFactory.create(AbstractSavedStateViewModelFactory.java:84)
AndroidRuntime:        at dagger.hilt.android.internal.lifecycle.HiltViewModelFactory.create(HiltViewModelFactory.java:109)
AndroidRuntime:        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.java:187)
AndroidRuntime:        at com.xxxx.view.MyFragment.onViewCreated(MyFragment.kt:58)
AndroidRuntime:        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performViewCreated(Fragment.java:3019)
AndroidRuntime:        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.createView(FragmentStateManager.java:551)
AndroidRuntime:        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStateManager.java:261)
AndroidRuntime:        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:1840)
AndroidRuntime:        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:1758)
AndroidRuntime:        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1701)
AndroidRuntime:        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManager.java:2849)
AndroidRuntime:        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManager.java:2784)
AndroidRuntime:        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentController.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentController.java:262)
AndroidRuntime:        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:478)
AndroidRuntime:        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.onStart(AppCompatActivity.java:246)
```

Usage:

What is a correct way to achieve this?

Comment: Can you include the entire stack trace? And where you are calling this code?

Comment: If you remove the `@AndroidEntryPoint` (and thus, remove Hilt from the equation), does it work then?

Comment: I am using @HiltViewModel annotation for my viewmodel - won't that be impacted?

Comment: You'd need to remove that also if you want to test if the problem is from Hilt or not, yes.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem when I go back and again switch to the same activity. I am not using hilt and am using get which should give me the same instance if it already exists.

```
pruebaViewModel = ViewModelProvider(this, InjectionSingleton.provideViewModelFactory(this)).get("HolaPrueba", PruebaViewModel::class.java)

class ViewModelFactory(
    private val savedStateRegistryOwner: SavedStateRegistryOwner,
    private val countDownTimerSession: CountDownTimerSession,
    private val dataProviderRenta4: DataProviderRenta4,
    private val encryptedSharedPreferencesManager: EncryptedSharedPreferencesManager,
    private val dataUserSession: DataUserSession,
) : AbstractSavedStateViewModelFactory(savedStateRegistryOwner, null) {

    companion object {
        var INSTANCE: ViewModelFactory? = null

        @Synchronized
        fun getInstance(
            savedStateRegistryOwner: SavedStateRegistryOwner,
            countDownTimerSession: CountDownTimerSession,
        dataProviderRenta4: DataProviderRenta4,
        encryptedSharedPreferencesManager: EncryptedSharedPreferencesManager,
        dataUserSession: DataUserSession
    ): ViewModelFactory {

        if (INSTANCE == null) {
            INSTANCE =
                ViewModelFactory(savedStateRegistryOwner, countDownTimerSession, dataProviderRenta4, encryptedSharedPreferencesManager, dataUserSession)
        }
        return INSTANCE!!

    }
}

override fun <T : ViewModel> create(key: String, modelClass: Class<T>, savedStateHandle: SavedStateHandle): T {
    Log.d(TAG, "l> key key key: $key")
    return modelClass.getConstructor(
        SavedStateHandle::class.java,
        DataProviderRenta4::class.java,
        DataUserSession::class.java,
        CountDownTimerSession::class.java,
        EncryptedSharedPreferencesManager::class.java
    ).newInstance(savedStateHandle, dataProviderRenta4, dataUserSession, countDownTimerSession, encryptedSharedPreferencesManager)
}
```

}

2022-07-21 13:29:25.863 22162-22162/com.r4.renta4.des E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.r4.renta4.des, PID: 22162
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.r4.renta4.des/com.r4.renta4.ui.prueba.PruebaActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: SavedStateProvider with the given key is already registered
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2778)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2856)
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1589)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: SavedStateProvider with the given key is already registered
at androidx.savedstate.SavedStateRegistry.registerSavedStateProvider(SavedStateRegistry.kt:110)
at androidx.lifecycle.SavedStateHandleController.attachToLifecycle(SavedStateHandleController.java:42)
at androidx.lifecycle.LegacySavedStateHandleController.create(LegacySavedStateHandleController.java:39)
at androidx.lifecycle.AbstractSavedStateViewModelFactory.create(AbstractSavedStateViewModelFactory.java:96)
at androidx.lifecycle.AbstractSavedStateViewModelFactory.create(AbstractSavedStateViewModelFactory.java:87)
at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.kt:187)
at com.r4.renta4.ui.prueba.PruebaActivity.setupViewModel(PruebaActivity.kt:24)
at com.r4.renta4.ui.base.BaseActivity.onCreate(BaseActivity.kt:149)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7009)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7000)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1214)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2731)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2856) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1589) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For me I have added two dependencies for navigation hilt and compose, you can check below

```
implementation 'androidx.hilt:hilt-navigation-compose:1.0.0'
implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-compose:2.5.3'
```